# Bucle infinito al leer el contenido，con fread， de un txt y volcar este a la salida por terminal con fwrite

Tags: c, fread

Al hacer un codigo de juguete sobre la lectura de un fichero txt y despues volcarlo sobre el terminal, despues de leer el contenido del fichero byte a byte y guardarlo en un char y despues escribir el contenido por consola. He acabado en un bucle infinito, el cual, aunque haya leido llegado al final del txt fread sigue siendo diferente de 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
FILE* file=NULL;
int c,ret,j=10;
char ptr[10], h[1];
if (argc!=2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <file_name>\n",argv[0]);
exit(1);
}
/* Open file */
if ((file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 
NULL)
    err(2,"The input file %s could 
not be opened",argv[1]);
/* Read file byte by byte */

while((c = fread(ptr,1,1,file) != 
EOF) /*&& j !=0*/ ){
    /* Print byte to stdout */
    fwrite(ptr,1,1,stdout);

    
    
    //j--;
    //printf("%d",c);
}

fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

He intentado que limitar las veces del bucle y me he dado cuenta que funciona correctamente，fread y write consiguen leer y escribor el contenido. Pero si elimino la limitación, no funciona.

El contenido del texto es variable, imaginemos que el fichero se llama Prueba.txt y su contenido sea "Prueba123".

Quisiera leer el contenido byte a byte y despues escribirlo por terminal.

Alguna ayuda sera agradecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El bucle sin fin lo tienes porque no estás evaluando correctamente el valor devuelto por `fread`

```
while((c = fread(ptr,1,1,file) != EOF)
```

Este bucle se repetirá hasta que el valor devuelto por `fread` (el cual almacenas en `c` sea igual a `EOF`.

El problema que tienes aquí es que `fread` devuelve el número de bytes leídos. `EOF` es una macro cuyo valor típico es `-1`. Por tanto, la única forma en que esto podría funcionar es si `fread` devolviese `-1` en algún momento... pero ya me explicarás tu por qué debería devolver `-1` cuando no ha podido leer ningún elemento ... en cuyo caso debería devolver 0. No se si me sigues.

De hecho la propia [documentación](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) de la función te lo explica:

> **Return Value**
>
> The total number of elements successfully read are returned as a size_t object, which is an integral data type. **If this number differs from the nmemb parameter, then either an error had occurred or the End Of File was reached**.

Es decir, si se produce un error o se ha alcanzado el final del archivo, entonces el valor devuelto por `fread` **no coincidirá** con el `nmemb`.

¿Y qué parámetro es ese? Basta con leerse la documentación para entenderlo:

> Following is the declaration for fread() function.
>
> `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`

Aquí podemos ver que `nmemb` es el tercer parámetro de la función.

Resumiendo, para evitar el bucle sin fin podemos dejar el bucle así:

```
while (fread(ptr, 1, 1, file) == 1) // Comprobar que return==nmemb
```

O, dado que solo estás leyendo de elemento en elemento

```
while (fread(ptr, 1, 1, file) != 0)
```

Comment: Verdad，muchas gracias por resolver mi duda. Tendre que leer me mejor el man...